# How can I modify individual elements in a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set with a value of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

How can I modify certain elements in a set? Something along the lines of changing the $5$ in $A$ to a $10$. Is this even possible?

Comment: The new set is $(A\setminus \{5\})\cup \{10\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change 5 to 10, you are essentially, removing one element, 5, and adding a new element 10 which means you now have a new set. So to answer your question, you can't just replace elements without changing the set itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace one element in a set with a different thing, the modified set certainly will not equal to the original set.